Variable mass term in $4$-force
Defining the $4$-momentum of a system of mass $m$ like $P^\mu=mU^\mu=(m\gamma c, \mathbf p)$, when computing the $3$-force,
$$\mathbf f=\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf p}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\mathrm d(m\gamma\mathbf u)}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\mathrm d(m\gamma)}{\mathrm dt}\mathbf u\,+\,m\gamma\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf u}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\mathbf f\cdot \mathbf u}{c^2}\,\mathbf u+m\gamma\,\mathbf a,$$
we differentiate the mass term wrt time whilst when computing the $4$-force,
$$F^\mu=\frac{\mathrm dP^\mu}{\mathrm d\tau}=\frac{\mathrm d(mU^\mu)}{\mathrm d\tau}=m\mathcal A^\mu,$$
they do not appear to differentiate $m$ wrt proper time, i.e, there doesn't appear a term $\dfrac{\mathrm dm}{\mathrm d\tau}U^\mu$. Why is that? Or am I confusing things?

Who is the 'they' that you are referring to after the 2nd equation set?

In my notes or even in Wikipedia.

You are correct to query this. The definition of 4-force is
$$
F = \frac{dP}{d\tau}
$$
and therefore, with $P = m U$ we get
$$
F = m \frac{dU}{d\tau} + \frac{dm}{d\tau} U.
$$
This only equates to $m A$ in the case of constant rest mass. However that case is sufficiently common that it may well be assumed without comment in many discussions. There is a terminology for this. If, when acting on a given body, a given force does not change the rest mass of the body, then it is said to be a {\em pure} force. If the rest mass can change that it is not a pure force.
The electromagnetic force on a point charge is a pure force.
A force acting on a composite body such as a spring might not be pure, because the rest mass of a spring can change if it is compressed or heated.
The case of a pure force leads to some useful simplifications in various equations. It gives $F^\mu U_\mu = 0$ for example.

Thank you, Andrew. This means that actually
$$\gamma\left(\dfrac{\mathbf f\cdot\mathbf u}{c},\mathbf f\right)=m\mathcal A^\mu+\frac{\mathrm dm}{\mathrm d\tau}U^\mu,$$
but just written $m\mathcal A^\mu$ because most of the times we treat problems with pure forces, no?

Almost, but in there is a further subtlety. The zeroth component of the 4-force is $(1/c)dE/d\tau$. For a pure force one can show that this is given by $\gamma {\bf f} \cdot {\bf u}/c$, but, careful: more generally that does not happen.

I see, thank you!
